# Prevent the row break on resizing animation system

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi in this system every div is set to become wider on hover while the others become thiner. With this system the black div move in the line below. I would like to find a system to prevent the line break and show all 4 div in the same line while resizing keeping 100% of page width. Could someone help me?

ADDITIONAL INFO: It should be work with bootstrap coloumn

JS FIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/z3bujoww/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="red">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" id="blue">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" id="green">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" id="black">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#red{background-color: red;height:20px;}
#blue{background-color: blue;height:20px;}
#green{background-color: green;height:20px;}
#black{background-color: black;height:20px;}
```

JQUERY:

```
 $('#red').hover(function(){ 

 $('#red').animate({
     width:'28%'
 },1000);
 $('#blue').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#green').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#black').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);}, function() {

 $('#red').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#blue').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#green').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#black').animate({
     width:'25%'},0); }); 

 $('#blue').hover(function(){ 

 $('#red').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#blue').animate({
     width:'28%'
 },1000);
 $('#green').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#black').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);}, function() {

 $('#red').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#blue').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#green').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#black').animate({
     width:'25%'},0); }); 

 $('#green').hover(function(){ 

 $('#red').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#blue').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#green').animate({
     width:'28%'
 },1000);
 $('#black').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);}, function() {

 $('#red').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#blue').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#green').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#black').animate({
     width:'25%'},0); }); 

 $('#black').hover(function(){ 

 $('#red').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#blue').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#green').animate({
     width:'24%'
 },1000);
 $('#black').animate({
     width:'28%'
 },1000);}, function() {

 $('#red').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#blue').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#green').animate({
     width:'25%'},0);
 $('#black').animate({
     width:'25%'},0); });
```

Comment: cant you use css :hover?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap class `col-sm-3` itself defines a default width. Thus it would interfere with your custom width.
You can solve your problem by reducing by `1%` everywhere.

[Check This Out.](https://jsfiddle.net/z3bujoww/5/)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to make it working keeping 100% page width.

Comment: I've solved with your solution but reducing just of 0.02%

Comment: ya because keeping total to 100 was a problem.